# MYSQL - Selecting a specific date range to get "current" popular screensavers

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a screensaver website. I want to display the CURRENT top 100 screensavers on the front page of the website.

What I mean is, "RECENT" top 100 screensavers. What would be an example query to do this?

My current one is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_screensavers WHERE WEEK(tbl_screensavers.DateAdded) = WEEK('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 week"))."') ORDER BY tbl_screensavers.ViewsCount, tbl_screensavers.DateAdded
```

This will select the most viewed ("tbl_screensavers.ViewsCount") screensavers that were added ("tbl_screensavers.DateAdded") in the last week.

However, in some cases there are no screensavers, or less than 100 screensavers, submitted in that week.

So, how can I perform a query which would select "RECENT" top 100 screensavers? Hopefully you have an idea of what I'm try to accomplish when I say "RECENT" or "CURRENT" top screensavers. -- aka. the most viewed, recently - not the most viewed, all-time.

Comment: btw, for my current query above, you must also stipulate the YEAR of dateadded or it would select week from all years

..hmm I guess this is a tough Q for everyone haha

Answer (score 1):

Given no other algorithm to weigh the value of a view vs. a recent view, you would just simply want

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_screensavers ORDER BY ViewsCount limit 100
```

However, to capture the concept of "recent" you may want to introduce an algorithm to weigh the recent-ness of a particular view.  One way to do that is to assign a daysOld score to each view and show the 100 with the lowest score (with this mechanism, low score is good like in golf).

I'm not enough of a MySQL guru to write the query for that, but it would involve summing up the score, computed based on daysOld=today-dateOfScore and then ordering the result set based on that score, with a limit of 100.

Comment: Something like:

SELECT *, WEEK(DateAdded)*ViewsCount as ViewsValue FROM tbl_screensavers ORDER BY ViewsValue DESC;

Comment: Now if only I knew how to make the above query account for the recent-ness... I am unsure how to determine recent-ness I guess that's my main issue here.

Comment: I suppose what it would need to be is:

For each 1x week, ViewsCount should be worth extra points. ??

Comment: or... just simply, for each "day old" it is, the ViewsCount is worth less.

know a query for that?

Comment: @Joe: Since you want the most recent views to count the most, you can either give a "penalty" to older views (which is easier math, just give a penalty of 1 per week/day/whatever and say low score is best) or give extra points for being recent (mathematically more challenging)

Comment: Yes I'm now trying to determine this penalty by finding the "DaysOld" value of the "DateAdded" field. However, I can't figure it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497746/mysql-selecting-how-many-days-old-a-field-is