# MySQL - Selecting how many "Days Old" a field is

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I select how many days old a field is based on it's "DateAdded" field?

E.g.:

```
SELECT DAYSOLD(tbl_stuff.DateAdded) as DaysOld 
  FROM tbl_stuff
```

Comment: I think the answer MAY be:

SELECT DAY(tbl_stuff.DateAdded)/TotalViews as DaysOld FROM tbl_stuff;

However, I'm not sure if this is actually Accurate.

UPDATE: I checked... it is not working this way >.<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), ts.dateadded) AS daysold
  FROM TBL_STUFF ts
```

Reference: [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function, to get the difference, in days, between `tbl_stuff.DateAdded` and `curdate()`.

For example :

```
mysql> select datediff(curdate(), '2010-03-15') as daysOld;
+---------+
| daysOld |
+---------+
|       8 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_days()` or `datediff()` functions.

MySQL has plenty of date functions, you can refer directly there, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/date-and-time-functions.html.